# Fiber-coupled diode laser in an SMD package?

Tags: surface-mount, optics, laser-diode

Does anyone manufacture a fiber-coupled diode laser in an SMD package?

Something like [this](http://www.rp-photonics.com/fiber_coupled_diode_lasers.html), but smaller.

Comment: Questions seeking recommendations for specific products or places to purchase them are off-topic as they are rarely useful to others and quickly obsolete.

Comment: To find a part like that you need to be ready to specify what wavelength laser, what power level, what modulation bandwidth, and what kind of fiber do you want on the output.

Comment: For example, http://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=4190

Comment: Asking if a specific type of product or form-factor exists is on topic!

Comment: @ThePhoton, Thanks, but as Passerby noted, I'm not asking for specific products or places to purchase them: I'm asking whether a particular *kind* of readymade component exists. I'm not after any specific wavelength, power level, bandwidth or fiber: just a compact form factor. Your link was helpful. Please feel free to make it into an answer :)

Comment: My feeling about questions like this is that a simple answer of "yes" would be severely downvoted. The only useful question would specify an example product, at which point it becomes a shopping question. If it walks like a duck...

Comment: @Passerby, usually when we ask "Does anybody <x> ?" we really mean, "Who <x>es?".

Comment: @sampablokuper, I'd be happy to give you some more pointers in chat. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mechanical loads which can be placed on the package by a fiber, along with the general need for considerable waste heat management, make a "pure" SMD package a bad idea. One exception: http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/70/475162_DS.pdf. You'll notice, though, that this only produces .3 mW, and the fiber is not connectorized. For any diode with more power, you need a physically larger package to dissipate heat, and once you start using a bigger package, SMT is not generally strong enough to reliably mount the part. There are a fair number of modules which are mechanically secured by screws, but with surface mount leads for electrical connection. These are generally (roughly) not much smaller than the unit you dislike.